# How do you use a WAV file in Eclipse?

Tags: java, swing, javasound

I've been trying to add audio to a project I've been doing. I found some code on here for HTML that is also supposed to work with file but it keeps saying:

```
 "Exception in thread "main" javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)  at LoopSound.main(LoopSound.java:15)"
```

The code:

```
public class LoopSound {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable  {
        File file = new File("c:\\Users\\rabidbun\\Pictures\\10177-m-001.wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        // getAudioInputStream() also accepts a File or InputStream
        AudioInputStream wav = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( file );
        clip.open(wav);
        // loop continuously
        clip.loop(-1000);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // A GUI element to prevent the Clip's daemon Thread
                // from terminating at the end of the main()
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Try the code with [`leftright.wav`](http://pscode.org/media/#sound).  BTW 1) This probably has nothing to do with the IDE. 2) Parts of that code look very familiar.  ;)

Comment: yah i got it from someone here cant site it cause i cant rember who but it is giving me a headache

Comment: well thers a slight problem the audio file needs to come from my computer and i had to change File file=new FILE.... from URL url =new URL.... so that this could get it from my computer. so that url wont work in it

Comment: *"well thers a slight problem the audio file needs to come from my computer"*  Well use some initiative (you won't get far in programming without it).  ***Download*** the `leftright.wav` to your computer and try it.